# Can I get a bounty refunded that was auto-awarded to a wrong answer?

Tags: support, bounty

I asked the following question: [Which of the versions is the latest?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/368384/), and raised a bounty for it. However, the bounty was awarded automatically, and the answer which got my bounty has misleading information.

It says Game 2 is CS 1.6 and NOT Condition Zero. But those screenshots are actually taken from Condition Zero game only. All of three games are Condition Zero. I had clearly mentioned it.

Can I get my bounty back? It's embarrassing.

Answer (score 6):

Bounties cannot be refunded. It looks like the answer was given it because it met the criteria for automatic rewarding:

- They were posted after the bounty was started, and
- They have a score of at least 2 (at the time the automatic awarding takes place), and
- They were not written by the bounty starter.

So half the amount was given to the person who got it automatically, if I am reading things right.

When you place a bounty, it does warn you that you won't get the rep back, I believe.

Comment: But it's embarrassing and pathetic.

Comment: @Vikas I'm sorry you feel that way, but there's nothing we can do. However, something to be aware of is that the bounty is actually attributed to *community* and not to you. This, along with your comments, should indicate you were not the one that awarded the bounty.